# Disk Error: failed command: READ DMA EXT

Tags: hard-disk, sata

I have a fairly old system board from 2010 and two newer hard drives (HGST 6-TB) running CentOS.  I repeatedly get the following errors in the dmesg output for each hard drive (proceeded by a loud clicking sound).

```
ata14: lost interrupt (Status 0x50)
ata14.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40d0002 action 0xe frozen
ata14: SError: { RecovComm PHYRdyChg CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
ata14.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
ata14.00: cmd 25/00:08:a8:d9:30/00:00:46:02:00/e0 tag 0 dma 4096 in
ata14.00: status: { DRDY }
ata14: hard resetting link
ata14: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
ata14.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata14.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
ata14: EH complete
```

What could this be?

Comment: I found the answers on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) for similar DMA hard disk questions helpful: - [How do I recover from a read DMA bootup error?](https://askubuntu.com/q/321277)
- [System locking up with suspicious messages about hard disk](https://askubuntu.com/q/13952)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old system and new disks? If the system's power supply is also old, it might be having problems keeping the voltages stable - and when the hard disks experience brief power "brown-outs", they reset and report errors to the operating system.

If you can, try borrowing a new PSU from somewhere and using it to run the system for a while. If replacing the PSU causes the errors to not happen any more, then the old PSU is starting to die.

Comment: OP: Actually, the PSU was the problem.  As I recall I purchased a new PSU and the problems disappeared.