# dmesg exceptions on connecting 8TB WD SATA drive

Tags: debian, hard-disk, sata

On init of the system under systemd the following output is observed from dmesg. I've included a bit before the exception too for context. `fdisk -l` does not list the new disk. I connected the drive while debian was running and didn't initially notice anything (I just tried to list the device). I then restarted with it connected and seen these exceptions on startup (they are repeated quite a few times)

```
[    9.445662] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[    9.491596] systemd-udevd[217]: starting version 215
[    9.552599] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input7
[    9.552605] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
[    9.552678] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input8
[    9.552681] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[    9.556504] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    9.558170] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: irq 48 for MSI/MSI-X
[    9.572940] wmi: Mapper loaded
[    9.582204] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000400-0x000000000000047F (\PMIO) (20140424/utaddress-254)
[    9.582212] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    9.582217] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20140424/utaddress-254)
[    9.582221] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    9.582223] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20140424/utaddress-254)
[    9.582228] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    9.582230] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20140424/utaddress-254)
[    9.582234] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000050F (\_GPE.GPIO) (20140424/utaddress-254)
[    9.582239] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    9.582240] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[    9.591159] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    9.594493] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[    9.594565] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[    9.594632] ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[    9.594703] ata4.00: cmd 25/00:08:00:2a:81/00:00:a3:03:00/e0 tag 25 dma 4096 in
         res 51/04:08:00:2a:81/00:00:a3:03:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[    9.594796] ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[    9.594864] ata4.00: error: { ABRT }
[    9.597764] ata4.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[    9.598186] ata4.00: failed to get NCQ Send/Recv Log Emask 0x1
[    9.598300] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[    9.599574] ata4.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[    9.599812] ata4.00: failed to get NCQ Send/Recv Log Emask 0x1
[    9.599818] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[    9.599836] ata4: EH complete
[    9.604646] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[    9.604718] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[    9.604786] ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[    9.604858] ata4.00: cmd 25/00:08:00:2a:81/00:00:a3:03:00/e0 tag 26 dma 4096 in
         res 51/04:08:00:2a:81/00:00:a3:03:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[    9.604950] ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[    9.605018] ata4.00: error: { ABRT }
[    9.605411] ata4.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[    9.605673] ata4.00: failed to get NCQ Send/Recv Log Emask 0x1
[    9.606237] ata4.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[    9.606467] ata4.00: failed to get NCQ Send/Recv Log Emask 0x1
[    9.606472] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[    9.606489] ata4: EH complete
```

The related [solved] problem contains a similar, but not the same, error message and my PSU works fine when connecting other disk drives, so I doubt it's that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disk Error: failed command: READ DMA EXT](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350772/disk-error-failed-command-read-dma-ext)

Comment: don't think so, see updated question.

Comment: If could be the cables or motherboard then. Also, maybe your disc does not support NCQ/AA, and you should have to edit your `/etc/default/grub` and at the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` add the `libata.force=noncq` parameter. Example: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.force=noncq"` (and of course, execute `update-grub` as root)